# How to search JSON data in MySQL by key and value?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am inserting my data in a database with json_encoded. Now I want to search in "feature", but the result is not exactly true.

MySQL query:

```
select * 
from `modul_69`  
where `extmod` like '%"68":%' 
  and `extmod` like '%"4"%' 
  and `extmod` not like '%"4":%'
```

Results:

row1 data:

```
{"68":["1","4","7"],"67":["14"],"75":["28"]} - true
```

row2 data:

```
{"68":["59"],"67":["1","11","13"],"75":["3","4","5","27"]} - false
```

I want select only `row1` by `key:68` and `value:4`

Please help

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: If you have a MySQL server version that allows you to use MySQL’s own JSON functionality - then use that. If you don’t - then don’t store data this way to begin with, but properly normalize.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it using [MySQL JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html), available since version 5.7:

```
select *
from t
where json_search(js -> '$."68"', 'one', '4') is not null
```

What this does is get the array that correspond to outer key `'68'` (using `->`, which is a syntactic sugar for `json_extract()`), and then search its content with `json_search()`; if a non-`null` value is returned, we have a match.

Comment: That `json_search()` function is nice

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but MSQL version is 5.5

Comment: @user3003830: 5.5 has no JSON support. Just upgrade. Otherwise, I would recommend against storing JSON in that database, since you have no easy way to manipulate it with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

To find if the value `'"4"'` is contained in the member `'"68"'`, you can first extract the array using [`JSON_EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) :

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(m.extmod, '$."68"')
FROM modul_69 m;
```

This outputs

```
["1", "4", "7"]
["59"]
```

To search in a JSON array if it contains a specific value, you can use [`JSON_CONTAINS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) :

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS('["1", "4", "7"]', '"4"', '$'); -- output is 1
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS('["59"]', '"4"', '$'); -- output is 0
```

Now you can combine both functions to get the rows that contains the expected value :

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE modul_69
(
  extmod JSON
);

INSERT INTO modul_69 VALUES ('{"68":["1","4","7"],"67":["14"],"75":["28"]}'), ('{"68":["59"],"67":["1","11","13"],"75":["3","4","5","27"]}');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM modul_69 m
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(m.extmod, '$."68"'),
                    '"4"',
                    '$') = 1;
```

**Output**

```
| extmod                                              |
| --------------------------------------------------- |
| {"67": ["14"], "68": ["1", "4", "7"], "75": ["28"]} |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wKqnbXFMYWb69fM6QMdsMs/0)